# How to get the name of the select element from another html field in Angular

Tags: html, angular, select

I have these two elements (select and a text field) I want to disable the text box if the name the user selects from the drop down is "Other". 
ex. clModal.idustryName !== 'Other'

Currently I only know how to get the ceModal.industryId because that is what I'm saving. How can I reference the name?

Here are my two elements

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="ceIndustry">Industry</label>
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryId" (ngModelChange)="markDirty()" name="ceIndustry" #ceIndustry="ngModel" required>
    <option [ngValue]=null>None selected</option>
    <option *ngFor="let industry of industryList" [value]="industry.code">{{industry.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div [hidden]="ceIndustry.valid || ceIndustry.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Industry is required</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="ceIndustryOther">Industry Other</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. Other industry info" [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryOther" (ngModelChange)="markDirty()" name="ceIndustryOther" [disabled]="(clModal.idustryName !== 'Other')">
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share values of `industryList ` ? Please check what values you are getting when you are selecting dropdown and cross check whether same is used in input disabled or not

Comment: Are you willing to switch to reactive forms? Personally I think reactive forms are the best option for anything other than the most trivial of forms

Comment: Piyush - The problem is the industrylist is being fetched from a web service so the id's associated with each item will change. So I want to look for the key/name of the industrylist, which will in many cases have "Other" as an option to select.

Comment: If you already know the industry code of `other` then pass directly that 
[disabled]="(clModal.idustryName !== 'code')" to input text

Comment: could you share `industryList ` data

Comment: the industry code changes depending on the web service I'm pulling. So I don't really know it. But the more direct question is, isn't there a way to check for the name "Other"?

Comment: Programoholic - industryList is just a key/value pair with names and ids. Where at least one of them is Other/id, where the id could be 12 or 544 or 43, etc , etc. The id will be different every time. But there will always be a "Other" option